# UITableViewController: uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary length]:

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Until now I was trying to set the hardcoded data as

```
self.transactions = @[@"Transaction 1", @"Transaction 2", @"Transaction 3"];
```

and everything seem to work out fine. Now I changed this to get the data from `JSON` file and it crashes the app. The relevant part that I changed is

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        NSDictionary *transactionsDictionary = [TransactionAPI getTransactionsForYear:2014 AndMonth:9];
        NSLog(@"Transactions:%@", [transactionsDictionary valueForKey:@"transactions"]);
        NSLog(@"Transactions Is Array:%@", @([[transactionsDictionary valueForKey:@"transactions"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]));
        self.transactions = [transactionsDictionary valueForKey:@"transactions"];
        [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    return self;
```

and the delegate code is

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.transactions.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = self.transactions[(NSUInteger) indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

The log I see is

```
2014-09-01 11:43:53.798 pennyapp-ios[51286:70b] Transactions:(
        {
        amount = "25.0";
        category = "Food & Drink";
        debit = 1;
        name = "White Elephant Thai";
        "transaction_date" = "Mon, 01 Sep 2014 03:01:52 -0000";
        uuid = "5fe79315-1378-4b3f-90b7-e820d5c786d8";
    },
        {
        amount = "2.0";
        category = "Food & Drink";
        debit = 1;
        name = "Apple Juice";
        "transaction_date" = "Fri, 29 Aug 2014 22:02:02 -0000";
        uuid = "1c4f3931-2de8-4791-b2b7-34fc1bb113a5";
    },
        {
        amount = "4.99";
        category = "Food & Drink";
        debit = 1;
        name = "India Bazar";
        "transaction_date" = "Fri, 29 Aug 2014 21:59:26 -0000";
        uuid = "bdcdd72f-f46b-47c1-b6fb-ba877e9ef1ce";
    },
        {
        amount = "48.59";
        category = "Food & Drink";
        debit = 1;
        name = Costco;
        "transaction_date" = "Mon, 25 Aug 2014 01:37:32 -0000";
        uuid = "153a4ca7-1a6e-471a-80a4-d5d087e18bef";
    },
        {
        amount = "1.0";
        category = "Food & Drink";
        debit = 1;
        name = "Patel Brothers";
        "transaction_date" = "Sun, 24 Aug 2014 21:34:11 -0000";
        uuid = "8e351586-00eb-41ef-8429-189ef31c3bad";
    },
        {
        amount = "60.81";
        category = Utilities;
        debit = 1;
        name = Comcast;
        "transaction_date" = "Sun, 24 Aug 2014 20:23:37 -0000";
        uuid = "36f24ec4-b906-425c-8983-b07f10dc2d63";
    },
        {
        amount = "8.82";
        category = Personal;
        debit = 1;
        name = "Samsung Tablet Case";
        "transaction_date" = "Sun, 24 Aug 2014 20:17:13 -0000";
        uuid = "2ee4a1fe-47b9-4b47-b908-e7eb9647e4e9";
    },
        {
        amount = "320.0";
        category = "Gifts & Donations";
        debit = 1;
        name = "Harit Gift";
        "transaction_date" = "Sat, 23 Aug 2014 00:01:27 -0000";
        uuid = "e070e9d1-7439-4169-a5d1-71e637723e1f";
    },
        {
        amount = "9.0";
        category = "Gifts & Donations";
        debit = 1;
        name = "Patel Brothers";
        "transaction_date" = "Sat, 23 Aug 2014 00:00:02 -0000";
        uuid = "8b8af28a-c679-411c-806a-52c35d0267c8";
    },
        {
        amount = "9.63";
        category = "Food & Drink";
        debit = 1;
        name = Sprouts;
        "transaction_date" = "Mon, 18 Aug 2014 00:23:10 -0000";
        uuid = "ea5624fe-8e76-4133-9f4b-238e9f823474";
    },
        {
        amount = "51.01";
        category = "Health & Medical";
        debit = 1;
        name = Vitamins;
        "transaction_date" = "Sun, 17 Aug 2014 01:25:31 -0000";
        uuid = "101d16e3-cc95-41e5-ba44-1c9ee0a6a2ce";
    },
        {
        amount = "23.0";
        category = "Food & Drink";
        debit = 1;
        name = Costco;
        "transaction_date" = "Sun, 17 Aug 2014 01:23:35 -0000";
        uuid = "33b495c1-fe7c-4a70-b8fa-8198c377f00b";
    },
        {
        amount = "11.47";
        category = "Health & Medical";
        debit = 1;
        name = Kaiser;
        "transaction_date" = "Thu, 14 Aug 2014 21:47:23 -0000";
        uuid = "8863196c-cb10-4f64-ab8c-cbf068ad05df";
    },
        {
        amount = "31.47";
        category = Transportation;
        debit = 1;
        name = Chevron;
        "transaction_date" = "Thu, 14 Aug 2014 21:47:04 -0000";
        uuid = "8422f5de-5733-4d81-9081-f5c69d8a629a";
    },
        {
        amount = "10.0";
        category = Personal;
        debit = 1;
        name = Laundry;
        "transaction_date" = "Tue, 12 Aug 2014 03:20:52 -0000";
        uuid = "7773fe4b-ee18-4343-9bb3-0e3072c3c56e";
    },
        {
        amount = "10.5";
        category = "Food & Drink";
        debit = 1;
        name = "India Bazar";
        "transaction_date" = "Sun, 10 Aug 2014 23:18:13 -0000";
        uuid = "409bd274-5f2d-4ba4-86c6-90f5f5014fe0";
    },
        {
        amount = "8.0";
        category = Home;
        debit = 1;
        name = "Dollar Tree";
        "transaction_date" = "Sun, 10 Aug 2014 23:17:49 -0000";
        uuid = "eaf23fca-8f5b-4e7a-93dc-1c4e29274351";
    },
        {
        amount = "12.98";
        category = "Food & Drink";
        debit = 1;
        name = "Patel Brothers";
        "transaction_date" = "Sun, 10 Aug 2014 16:20:11 -0000";
        uuid = "3dfba99b-7278-450e-8e82-ee9761181294";
    },
        {
        amount = "18.47";
        category = Personal;
        debit = 1;
        name = "Payless footwears";
        "transaction_date" = "Sun, 10 Aug 2014 01:05:08 -0000";
        uuid = "925d9cf1-9fc7-4062-99ad-4fdfb6eaf225";
    },
        {
        amount = "8.28";
        category = "Food & Drink";
        debit = 1;
        name = "India Bazar";
        "transaction_date" = "Thu, 07 Aug 2014 04:17:18 -0000";
        uuid = "6cab973d-7641-467c-9284-ebd441e97750";
    },
        {
        amount = "17.59";
        category = "Health & Medical";
        debit = 1;
        name = Kaiser;
        "transaction_date" = "Tue, 05 Aug 2014 18:25:33 -0000";
        uuid = "eb23dc2d-276e-4bc6-8fd5-bd952558465a";
    },
        {
        amount = "28.0";
        category = Transportation;
        debit = 1;
        name = Chevron;
        "transaction_date" = "Tue, 05 Aug 2014 04:17:44 -0000";
        uuid = "a34e57f3-0877-4763-a7fe-955f00a36ec3";
    },
        {
        amount = "1818.0";
        category = Home;
        debit = 1;
        name = Rent;
        "transaction_date" = "Mon, 04 Aug 2014 03:20:19 -0000";
        uuid = "df2047a3-112e-4d82-b1ba-c09a66bb69cd";
    },
        {
        amount = "49.5";
        category = "Food & Drink";
        debit = 1;
        name = Costco;
        "transaction_date" = "Mon, 04 Aug 2014 03:19:04 -0000";
        uuid = "9599590e-d8e1-4cdd-a81f-3d6bbac79f66";
    },
        {
        amount = "64.36";
        category = "Food & Drink";
        debit = 1;
        name = "India Bazar";
        "transaction_date" = "Mon, 04 Aug 2014 03:18:54 -0000";
        uuid = "44d30643-bba3-471a-a8f8-2f71aa2e5f1d";
    },
        {
        amount = "35.0";
        category = Utilities;
        debit = 1;
        name = "Phone Metro PCS";
        "transaction_date" = "Sat, 02 Aug 2014 21:48:45 -0000";
        uuid = "2fb93a75-69f9-49cf-a93a-f7343dcba59f";
    },
        {
        amount = "60.81";
        category = Utilities;
        debit = 1;
        name = Comcast;
        "transaction_date" = "Sat, 02 Aug 2014 14:36:46 -0000";
        uuid = "112c43eb-6e5e-4b4d-9079-6d896fa11b01";
    }
)
2014-09-01 11:43:53.801 pennyapp-ios[51286:70b] Transactions Is Array:1
2014-09-01 11:43:53.809 pennyapp-ios[51286:70b] -[__NSCFDictionary length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10bf65a50
2014-09-01 11:43:53.811 pennyapp-ios[51286:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10bf65a50'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001023c7495 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010212699e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010245865d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001023b8d8d ___forwarding___ + 973
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001023b8938 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x00000001009b259d -[UILabel font] + 34
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000100b320cc -[UITableViewCellLayoutManager layoutSubviewsOfCell:] + 5307
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000100a593be -[UITableViewCell layoutSubviews] + 71
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000100891993 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 354
    9   QuartzCore                          0x0000000104fbd802 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 151
    10  QuartzCore                          0x0000000104fb2369 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 363
    11  QuartzCore                          0x0000000104fb21ea _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    12  QuartzCore                          0x0000000104f25fb8 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 252
    13  QuartzCore                          0x0000000104f27030 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 394
    14  QuartzCore                          0x0000000104f2769d _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 89
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102392dc7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102392d37 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102372522 __CFRunLoopRun + 946
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102371d83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001036e4f04 GSEventRunModal + 161
    20  UIKit                               0x0000000100831e33 UIApplicationMain + 1010
    21  pennyapp-ios                        0x00000001000013f3 main + 115
    22  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001033665fd start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

What is the issue? I could not debug this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you are not maintaining an array of Transactions, but you are maintaining a dictionary of it. Type Coercion is tricky in objective C, `NSDictionary` is passing as `NSArray` and your app is crashing at `numberOfItemsInSection`.

To solve this issue, however, you need to create a model that resembles your JSON structure. And create an array of these models and makes this as your `dataSource`. At `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, you get the corresponding model by,

```
TransactionModel *model = [transactions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.label.text = model.name;
//So on and so forth
```

**Edit #1**

In case you are stuck with creating the model file, here is how it should be like:

*TransactionModel.h*

```
@interface TransactionModel : NSObject 

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *category;

//So on and so forth...

- (id) initWithTransactionDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary;
```

*initWithTransactionDictionary method*

```
-(id) initWithTransactionDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary { 
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        if([dictionary objectForKey:@"name"] != nil) {
            self.name = [dictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
        }
        //So on and so forth...
    }
    return self;
}
```

**Edit #2**

In case you are stuck with creating the array of transactions, add this in your `initWithStyle` method

```
for(int i = 0; i < [transactions count]; i++) {
    TransactionModel *currentModel = [[TransactionModel alloc]initWithDictionary:[transactions objectAtIndex:i]];
    [self.transactionModels addObject:currentModel];
}
```

Comment: and where should I instantiate my array of `TransactionModel`? in `TransactionTableViewController`? at `initWithStyle`?

Comment: Yes. That's where you should put it. :)

Comment: Thanks, I will try and let you know. btw, is it generally a good practice to have models on client? I know for `JavaScript` we do have models that represent the model on server, just curious for `iOS`

Comment: It is a common paradigm in iOS that heavily follows the MVC pattern.

Comment: I tried and it works really well, thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

You used to have `NSStrings` inside your`transactions` array. And it was correct to do the following:

```
cell.textLabel.text = self.transactions[(NSUInteger) indexPath.row];
```

You would take a string and apply it as text. But now there are dictionaries inside array instead of strings. But you are still trying to take an object from the array and apply it as text. This is impossible, because there are dictionaries there now. And a dictionary doesn't have method `length`. That's why your app crashes. You should take a string from the dictionary (it's `name` field most likely) and apply it as text